# Jetpack Compose Lazy Column rows with each row having a saveable and clickable checkbox value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I have a list of rows where each row has a checkbox icon that can be clicked or not. I want to be able to have a user check the box and then my app should save that state. My current approach may be incorrect which is what is causing this transient bug.

Current Approach:
I have a room db that stores the state of each item's checkbox status. Then, I display each row inside a lazy column composable. Each row's checkbox value is set initially with the current db item's status, then the user can change that value by clicking on the button. When the button is clicked I save the new value to a view model that holds all the current updated values and when the user saves their selections, the view model with all the updated values writes its values to the room db.

The row code looks like:

```
@Composable
fun RowItemDisplay(item: RowItem) {
    val updateDataViewModel: UpdateDataViewModel = viewModel()

    val checkBoxStatus = remember { mutableStateOf(
        item.checkBoxStatus
    ) }

    val color = if (checkBoxStatus.value) { Color.Black } else { Color.LightGray }
    val icon = if (checkBoxStatus.value) { Icons.Filled.CheckCircle } else { Icons.Outlined.AddCircle }

    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .size(40.dp)

    ) {
        Text(
            text = "  ${item.name}",
            color = Color.Black,
            modifier = Modifier.align(CenterVertically)
        )
        Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
        IconButton(onClick = {
            checkBoxStatus.value = !(checkBoxStatus.value)
            updateDataViewModel.updateMap[item.id] = checkBoxStatus.value
        }) {
               Icon(icon, tint = color, contentDescription = "Add",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(CenterVertically)
                        .size(24.dp)
               )
        }
    }
}
```

The area of issue here is the `checkBoxStatus`. Sometimes the checkBoxStatus for a row is using the memory reference from another (based on debug print logs) which causes an erroneous display for the checkbox status. If I scroll away from the row and back to the row it recomposes and gets its own checkBoxStatus variable which shows the correct information.

I was expecting that each row would instantiate its own variables but as I have said, based on logs (the memory location for the variable is identical across rows), sometimes a row reuses another row's variable references. I am unsure how/why this would happen. Honestly, I feel my entire approach feels wrong. I tried to update the room db value directly in the IconButton onChange action but this fails to have the UI re-compose to show the current value.

Comment: You can checkout my answer similar to this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77852780/checkbox-state-is-not-changing-in-jetpack-compose-lazycolumn-items/77854179#77854179

Comment: The RowItem is already a data class (one that is also decorated with @Entity) that is stored in a room DB. The state of the check boxes should persist even after an app is closed. So I think I already have that covered.

Comment: It it is already data class then check how to update the list with new data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LazyColumn (and RecyclerView) can reuse elements. It's known optimization which helps to render items faster. For example this reduces memory allocation if user scrolls list too fast.

However here it's not the reason of your problem. It seems that your bug is in line where you create `checkBoxStatus`. When `RowItemDisplay` called it reads value of current item and creates state. When user performs click only local state changes. Your `item.checkBoxStatus` stays same. Changed occured only in `checkBoxStatus` which is another variable. To fix this you can either keep `State<Boolean>` in your `RowItem` class instead of simply boolean, or in your click handler add

```
IconButton(onClick = {
            checkBoxStatus.value = !(checkBoxStatus.value)
            item.checkBoxStatus = !item.checkBoxStatus
```

Comment: I actually am updating the value. Just in a non-intuitive way. The RowItem is actually an entity class stored in a room DB. I collect all the updated list values in a view model and then batch updates all values when the user clicks a save button. That is what ```updateDataViewModel.updateMap[item.id] = checkBoxStatus.value``` is doing. Just changing the value of the item does not seem to update the actual value in the DB. I can switch to calling the insert directly ```roomViewModel.update(item)``` in the onClick but the error still persists

Comment: I actually seemed to have found a strange (to me) fix. I changed ```val color = if (checkBoxStatus.value) { Color.Black } else { Color.LightGray }``` and the icon value to use item.checkBoxStatus for their if/else checks instead of hasBeen. I then had to create a new dummy value ```val dummy = if (checkBoxStatus.value) {""} else {""}``` and included that in my icon text (otherwise the recompose never happens?). Then with the code change you recommended for ```item.checkBoxStatus = !item.checkBoxStatus``` (plus the update call for room DB) it seems to work. Does this make sense?

Comment: I'd recommend to read about single source of truth in state (for example here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state ). You should never change local variable in composable which initiated with your outer state. Because in case of recomposition it's unclear should it use value which is set initially (in line with val checkBoxStatus = ... item.checkBoxStatus .... Or should it use new value which you set after onClick. Your solution may work right now on your device but there is no guarantees that it's stable solution.

Comment: Also you can read this codelab ( https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state?index=..%2F..index#11 ) and examine this example from google ( https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetchat/app/src/main/java/com/example/compose/jetchat/conversation/Conversation.kt )

Comment: Thanks. Ill review the documentation you shared. I appreciate the help.