# Jetpack Compose how to clear all checkboxes in lazycolumn compose using a button in a different composable

Tags: android, button, checkbox, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I am looking for a solution on how to clear all checkboxes in lazycolumn compose using a button in a different composable.

So what I am trying to do it that one can check one or multiple checkboxes in the ParentItemComposable that are under the ObjectComposable. Then be able to clear all selections using the ClearAllButton composable

This is the code I have tried below

```
@Composable
fun ParentItemComposable(
    reload: Boolean,
    viewModel: EtfFilterViewModel,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier

) {
    val itemsList by remember {
        mutableStateOf(etfFilterViewModel.getEParentList)
    }
    Column() {

        LazyColumn(
            Modifier
                .background(color = PaleGrey50)
                .padding(bottom = 80.dp)
        ) {

            items(itemsList.sortedBy { it.title }) { parentItem ->
                val title: String = when (parentItem.title) {
                    "geography" -> {
                        "Geography"
                    }

                    "assetClass" -> {
                        "Asset Class"
                    }

                    "focusStyle" -> {
                        "Focus / Style"
                    }

                    else -> {
                        "Other"
                    }
                }
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 5.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(color = White)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = title,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
                    )
                }

                Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp)) {
                    parentItem.filterObjectList.sortBy {
                        it.name
                    }
                    parentItem.filterObjectList.forEach { filterObject ->

                        ObjectComposable(
                            filterObject,
                            viewModel,
                            itemsList.indexOf(parentItem),
                            parentItem.filterObjectList.indexOf(filterObject),
                        )
                    }
                    parentItem.filterObjectList.filter { i -> i.isChecked }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
private fun ObjectComposable(
    filterObject: FilterObject,
    viewModel: ViewModel,
    …..
) {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        val checkedState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        val context = LocalContext.current
        Checkbox(
            checked = checkedState.value,
            onCheckedChange = {
                checkedState.value = it
                ….
                viewModel.updateFilteredListOfStrings(filterObject.name)
            },
            enabled = true,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp)
        )
        Text(text = efilterObjectname)
    }
}


@Composable
fun ClearAllButton(
    onButtonClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = { onButtonClick() },
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = PaleGrey50,
                contentColor = Secondary
            ),
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, color = Secondary),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(R.string.clear_all),
                fontSize = FontSize.Small,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

What I am expecting is that ClearAllButton composable will clear all Checkboxes checked in ParentItemComposable lazycolum

Comment: can you share your Data class definition?. Because You need to maintain a flag in That Data Class Whether is checked or not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77852780/checkbox-state-is-not-changing-in-jetpack-compose-lazycolumn-items/77854179#77854179 you can check out this answer

Comment: You are getting the list from the EtfFilterViewModel. You can have a flag for checkbox in your data class and update it in the viewmodel whenever user checks the box. Also, when the clearAll button is selected, you can disable the flags in your list so that all the checkboxes will be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MutableStateList in your viewModel holding your data entity containing a boolean variable that checkBox observe.then you can iterate the list and modify it's item by means of invoking the copy method of the Kotlin Data Class.

MutableStateList is a state list, so if it's value change a composition reading it's item will recompose.

Firstly, you create a MutableStateList in your ViewModel holding your data entity namely parentItem. Secondly, you modify the construction of your parentItem, adding a boolean variable which your checkBox composable read. Thirdly, you invoke the items method in LazyColumn directly passing the list as the argument which controls how many items will be drawn. Finally, your checkBox read the boolean variable contained in your parentItem, Then you can alter the boolean variable to control the state of the checkbox.